# Iterating through multiple subdirectories to load large batch data

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, loops, zsh

newbie to coding and am making a legislative database for use in academic work. I have downloaded the California legislative information into a directory on a partitioned portion of my HD. Loaded the schema to the MySQL DB with no issues, downloaded the data and am having problems getting it uploaded. Lets call my workspace home directory home, within that directory are my modules (I have node in there but I would love to avoid using it until I make an app), my json package and settings files and a subdirectory called pubinfo. This is all set up.

Within the pubinfo directory are my sql table files, and shell commands for loading the data into mysql where I have a DB with tables ready for data insertion, as well as subdirectories for legislative sessions labeled from 2001-2019 by sessions (2001, 2003, and so on by 2 years). The loadData.sh file is below, and the instructions from the California data website said to download these files, unzip them, then to run them on my pubinfo directory...

```
if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
  echo Usage: .loadData.sh
  exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$MYSQL_PWD" ]; then
  read -p "Please enter root password:" MYSQL_PWD
  export MYSQL_PWD=${MYSQL_PWD}
fi

do
  if [ -e ${lcTable}.dat ]; then
    echo Processing table: ${lcTable}
    if [ -z "$MYSQL_PWD" ]; then
      mysql -uroot -p -Dcapublic -v -v -f < ${lcTable}.sql 2>&1 > ${lcTable}.log
    else
      mysql -uroot    -Dcapublic -v -v -f < ${lcTable}.sql 2>&1 > ${lcTable}.log
    fi
  fi
done < "tables_lc.lst"
```

When ran, the out put on my zsh terminal is '/usr/local/bin/loadData.sh: line 29: location_code_tbl.sql: No such file or directory', I also have to add that I symlinked the shell file into my path so that the variable could be called in a global setting. I plan to eliminate it once this is all uploaded. I suppose I could symlink all the sql tables as well, but I know there has to be an easier way to iterate through subdirectories while using the sql tables and files in my main directory. I just am not familiar with zsh or bash, I had to take an Udemy course just to set up the MySQL DB. Anyways, I was hoping someone would be able to help, if you have any questions that I did not address here I can answer. Oh and if there is any question on my machine, it is a newer Mac book pro, running the most current mysql version and my editor is visual studio code in addition to the good old terminal.

Thanks!

Comment: please show code for loadData.sh

Comment: what you see above is the loadData.sh file in my home/pubinfo directory, I need to iterate that over my home/pubinfo/pubinfo_yyyy subdirectories while using the .sql files in my home/pubinfo directory to read in the data.

I just tried `export MYSQL_PWD= pwhere
cd /Volumes/macdata/projects/NLP_thesis/home/pubinfo
for file in */**; do bash loadData.sh; done` it is still running but I am not even sure if it will work properly and its taking FOREVER. there are well over a million files in the subdirectories.

Comment: it complains about line 29 and script has only 20. anyway whats the output for "echo Processing table: ${lcTable}", and are you use full path for files in tables_lc.lst?